# How to write a sql query to group rows based on the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Above table is my data from multiple tables, and I want to be query on it like, its result will be shown as below

[image]

I tried using group by clause but I didn't achieve the same structure.
Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: I highly recommend not doing that in SQL and handling this kind of logic in your application. If that's possible.

Comment: The desired result table of your question is an HTML not a SQL table. So, the functionality you ask for, has to be implemented on client-side, after data have been fetched from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest method is to subtract a constant value to get the "adjacent" values.  The following returns a separate row for each id and range:

```
select id, min(year), max(year), data_source
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, data_source order by year) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, (year - seqnum), data_source
order by id, min(year);
```

This is how I would recommend showing the data.  But if you want it with a big concatenated string, you can use an additional level of aggregation:

```
select id,
        string_agg(concat(min_year, '-' + convert(varchar(255), nullif(max_year, min_year)), ': ', data_source), '
') within group (order by min_year)
from (select id, min(year) as min_year, max(year) as max_year, data_source
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, data_source order by year) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by id, (year - seqnum), data_source
     ) t
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29768fe85bf7a5bac77d27516f481630) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can group values in string if that suits you:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  STRING_AGG(concat(year,': ',data_source), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY year) AS data_source_groupped
FROM t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Example on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8e6ba/12

NOTE: You might use in separator CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) if needed. </p

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the analytical functions, sub-query and group by as follows:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  STRING_AGG(concat(year,': ',data_source), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY year) AS data_source_groupped
FROM (select t.id, t.datasource, 
             case when count(1) > 1 then concat(min(year),'-',max(year)) else min(year) end as year 
        from (select t.*, 
                     sum(case when data_source = lead_Data_source then 0 else 1 end) as sm 
                from (select t.*, 
                             lead(data_source) over (partition by id order by year) as lead_Data_source 
                        from your_table t ) t) t
     group by id, datasource, sm
) t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```